# Should I care about optimizing my code which is writing into the mobile device memory?

Tags: ios, iphone

Lets take a Swift and iPhone example:

NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(objects, forKey: "key")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

There are some circumstances where an instant write is desired.

Theoretically how many times could I run this code in an app until it ruins some of the memory for good?

Lets say I have this code running 10 times in my app per run.
Lets say the app is used 3 times per day.

Is this a question to consider during app creation or coding?

In other words should we care about NAND P/E metrics for the present devices?

Comment: By the way, there is no need to call `synchronize`

Comment: There is a need sometimes to definitively write to flash memory (e.g.: during app multitasking.

Comment: No, since `NSUserDefaults` instances are shared in memory there is no need to call synchronise to ensure multiple threads have updated data.  From the docs - *use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though you have not made any changes*  You might also use it to synchronise with an extension which is running in a different process space

Comment: Thanks Paulw11. I am not concerned about the threads of the same app. This is about multitasking between apps, shared app extensions, which cannot communicate through shared memory.

Answer (score 1):

The memory used for this is the internal SD card, and that would be good for a hundred thousand write cycles or more. One should not pointlessly write data out more often than necessary, for instance code that modifies user defaults should update all of them and *then* flush/synchronize once rather than once per setting, but the phone itself is likely to be damaged or upgraded and discarded long before the SD card's write-cycle limit is reached.

Comment: I am aware of these. Would like to see some concrete metrics.

Comment: Those depend on too many things: the exact brand and model of the flash memory card, the wear-leveling algorithm in the controller, what all the other software on the phone is doing. Anything more than general estimates would only apply to one specific model of phone at most. Overall though, the minimum you can expect is still greater than the likely lifetime of the phone so optimizing specifically for flash lifetime on a modern smartphone is like optimizing for minimal memory usage on a modern PC with 8-16GB of RAM and subject to the same rule of thumb.

Comment: Thanks Todd. I have read a figure of ~10k possible rewrites which could be easily achieved in a year or two. Then this figure is probably false.